# To float or not to float... your layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

I recently got into the discussion that `float` can be used *in* layout design, but should not be used *for* layout design. To specify, it can be used to `float` certain elements, but not position entire semantic sections and containers with respect to each other. Although the individual cited a couple sources ([source 1](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/07/17/floats-dont-suck-if-you-use-them-right/), [source 2](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101)) that could lead one to believe that `float` is hard to work with in some layout situations, I don't see any evidence linking to a specification to support the claim that it should not be used *for* layout.

If you can use `float` to position small portions of your layout, why not extend this technique for the big picture? i.e. the whole layout.

I know there are new techniques coming out like the [flexible box layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) and some others, but they are still drafts and are not supported currently. `inline-block` seems like a good candidate but sometimes you just need that `float` fix, and there are hacks to get this to work in older browsers as well.

So I guess my question is... is it true that `float` should not be used for layout? Is it a non-semantic or outdated technique nowadays, akin to the `table` layouts of yesteryear?

Comment: Maybe I should remove the second part of my question about which technique to use so I don't have my question removed? Just wondering... it's always helpful to comment on something before you downvote so people know what the problem is.

Comment: You are correct; as far as I know, there is no semantic rule for or against floats, therefore this is opinion-based and therefore off-topic. I didn't downvote, but I did close-vote your question.

Comment: But you just answered the question then in saying that "there is no semantic rule for or against floats"... so it's not opinion-based, it's fact-based...?

Comment: Floating _has_ been used for layouting for a long time – but IMHO basically because it was the _only_ tool we had; it was never _intended_ to be used for it on that scale. I think you can’t really argue with “semantics” here – because CSS’ job _is_ mostly visual, and therefor semantic “concerns” don’t actually apply here. And we are getting “better” tools at our hands nowadays (flex box model f.i.), that have less hassles than using floating for layouts has (clearing, containing floated elements, etc.)

Comment: No; because there is no semantic rule that says you should or shouldn't use them, it **is** opinion-based.

Comment: Eh, CSS has pretty much nothing to do with HTML semantics. I've never heard someone say "don't float an `<article>`" or whatever it is you're saying. I don't see it in your two linked articles either. Really can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: @David Ok, so the **fact** is (not opinion): "there is no semantic rule that says you should or shouldn't use them". How is that subjective?? That's all I wanted to know. Geez...

Comment: Yes, e.g. The fact is that there are no facts here, only opinions.

Comment: @David Are semantics all just opinions? If so then why don't we close-vote all semantic questions on SO...

Comment: In reality, **good** practice and **bad** practice bears the same weight as good vs. evil. We all know that it is wrong to murder, not because there is some rule book *that everyone follows* that says this, but because we just know it. There is no universal law that says that they are true, but we all know and recognize them to be true. The same applies to semantics. We, as a collective group of developers, see that certain methods are better than others; as a whole, we have not surveyed your particular question, so this is you opening the debate on the question, which is not meant for S.O.

Comment: @David The many books of law explicitly state that we cannot murder... Not sure where you were going with that. In any case, all I wanted to know is if there's a specific spec (w3c perhaps?) that explicitly says we should not use float for layout. In any case my question has been answered. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @MattK But *why* were those books written? When the earth came to be, those books didn't exist. We **created** them because we all understand what is good and what is evil.

Comment: Basically if anyone ever says to me "You shouldn't use floats for THAT!" I should never ask why... at least not on this site.

Comment: @MattK - You should ask why. And the only acceptable answer is because THAT can be done more conveniently by a specific alternative means. (for some definition of "conveniently" that is satisfactory to you)

Comment: @Alohci Seems like the community disagrees about whether I should ask why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantics in the jargon-sense are simply a way of formatting **HTML** so that search engines can parse the data with some sort of context. Semantics in a broader sense is how you code your site so that other developers can pull meaning from your coding style.

Floats are simply a tool in your tool belt and have no semantic context whatsoever. Additionally, floats are so widely used that it would be incongruous to say that they shouldn't be used. There are plenty of frameworks that rely on floats as part of their integral structure (Bootstrap, Gumby, Foundation, Skeleton, etc).

I can speak, however, to the difficulty of using floats. For someone just starting with CSS it can be hard to understand what exactly is going on with floats. In addition, you have clearing and in-flow and out-of-flow elements. It can certainly be confusing. However, floats are absolutely a cornerstone of the CSS specification and I couldn't imagine doing my job without them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative answer! Makes me feel a little better after all the comments, downvotes, and close-votes I received. Just trying to learn!

Comment: I understand! I have had similar questions on SO. It just seems that most members expect questions in a certain format and when that isn't the case the results are unpredictable!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is heavily dependent on floats, and its probably the most used CSS library.  That being said, for every fan of bootstrap, theres someone there to say that its not best practice.

**Do what works for you**

Comment: "Do what works for you". Yes. But know the full set of options, so you can choose the right tool for every situation. Don't let `float` be your [golden hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)